# After resizing my windows partition of a dual boot windows/ubuntu, my ubuntu is corrupted

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, resize

I have a dual boot Asus laptop with windows 8.1 and ubuntu 18.04.
Originally windows had 450 GB and Linux 50 GB.
I shrinked my winwdows by 30GB by using diskpart to offer them to ubuntu... this is where it went wrong:

I can still boot on windows but no longer on Ubuntu (where I have lots of important data).
I booted on live Ubuntu with USB flash drive and run boot-repair. I got log pasted below.
Faulty parition is /dev/sda5.
Filesystem is not even recognized...

Help much appreciated
Thanks

AG

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/7qHdXTSgQz/

Comment: I suspect that your partition table got messed up when you did the resize. Curiously enough, sda5 looks like it points to sda3. Here's the help for testdisk... http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step. You might also look at `gdisk` to repair the partition table... `man gdisk`.

Comment: testdisk did not recognize the /dev/sd5 partition:

Disk /dev/sda - 525 GB / 489 GiB - CHS 63841 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
>P MS Data                     2048     616447     614400
 P MS Data                   616448     819199     202752 [NO NAME]
 P MS Data                  1081344  861241343  860160000
 P MS Data                922681342 1025609725  102928384
I can list files in partition 3 but not in partition 4:

Comment: Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.

Comment: I finally ended up restoring a disk copy I did few weeks ago with dd
Now I have my partitions working but I lost few weeks of work...
Before restoring I did a rescue copy of damaged partition, so now for this partition I have a sane partition verison with old data and a copy of faukty parition with recent data, but which I do not know how to recover ! I tried a photorec on this faulty partition but could not recover the files of interest (I did a string search in the recovered files but could not find recent strings I remeember having in latest files...)

Comment: Does `gparted` see the faulty partition?

Comment: I did:
sudo losetup /dev/loop100 image.dd (where image.dd is a rescue of faulty partition), then gparted /dev/loop100, which gives:Unit -.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
======================
libparted : 3.2
======================
/dev/loop100: unrecognised disk label

Comment: I guess you're right... the partition is really messed up. It looked like in the report that the UUID was missing, and this says the label is unrecognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the Ubuntu 18.04 and it give the option about the old version data and program. So you don't erase all previous data and files and reinstall Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: the problem is that the older ubuntu partition is not seen (filesystem is not even recognized), so I strongly suspect that if I reinstall ubuntu it will not even ask me about data and program